# Fix AttributeError: module 'this' has no attribute 'stemmedWords' python

Tags: python, attributes

I have the following two files, ProcessText.py and test.py, yet when I run test.py I get the error above. I have checked all of the code and there is nothing wrong with the attribute settings(I think). I am new to python but not programming, so if I'm doing something stupid please let me know :). From what I've gathered online it's something to do with the importing, but I don't quite understand what import is messing with what.

```
from ProcessText import ProcessText

class test:
    input = "input string goes here"
    ProcessText(input)
    tfDict = ProcessText.setTFIDF(input)
    for k, v in tfDict:
        print(k," : ",v )
```

```
import math
import string
import this

from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

class ProcessText:
    tfDict = dict()
    stemmedWords = []
    lemmatizedWords = ""
    stemmedWordsRem = []
    sentences = []
    def __init__(self, input):
        lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
        text = word_tokenize(input)
        ps = PorterStemmer()
        this.stopWordsRem = [word for word in text if not word in stopwords.words()]  # removes stop words from input
        for each in this.stopWordsRem:  # stems input words
            this.stemmedWords.append(ps.stem(each))
        this.lemmatizedWords = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(w) for w in stemmedWords]  # lemmatizes each input word
        this.lemmatizedWords = ''.join(this.lemmatizedWords)
        this.emPunctuation = this.lemmatizedWords.translate(
            str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))  # strips punctuation from string
        this.sentences = this.lemmatizedWords.split(".")

    def setTFIDF(input):
        for word in this.remPunctuation:  # Finds the TF value of each word
            termsCount = 0
            if not (word in this.tfDict):
                for words in this.lemmatizedWords:
                    if (words == word):
                        termsCount += 1
                this.tfDict[word] = termsCount

        for k, v in this.tfDict.items():  # Finds the TF-IDF value of each word in the input text MIGHT need to add log to this
            documentsWithWord = 0
            for sentence in this.sentences:
                if sentence.find(k):
                    documentsWithWord += 1
            this.tfDict[k] = math.log((len(sentence) / documentsWithWord) * v)
        return this.tfDict
```

Comment: In the 2nd code block, line 3 says `import this`. Are you aware that this module is just a [Python easter egg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37301273/attributes-of-python-module-this)? It has none of the attributes that you're trying to access in your code.

Answer (score 1):

In the code:

```
from ProcessText import ProcessText
```

Try to use a different name for your module and your class

From [PEP-8: Package and Module Names:](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

> **Package and Module Names:** should have short, all-lowercase names. Underscores can be used in the module name if it improves readability. Python packages should also have short, all-lowercase names, although the use of underscores is discouraged.

> **Class Names:** Class names should normally use the CapWords convention. The naming convention for functions may be used instead in cases where the interface is documented and used primarily as a callable.

Something more correct would be:

```
from myclass import MyClass
```

Do you have a module called this?, why are you importing it?

```
import this
```

From what I see in the ProcessText class, you are trying to define instance variables (I know this because the way you are doing it is similar to java):

```
class ProcessText:
    tfDict = dict()
    stemmedWords = []
    lemmatizedWords = ""
    stemmedWordsRem = []
    sentences = []
```

But to declare instance variables and initialize them, in python it is done in a different way,:

```
class ProcessText:
    def __init__(self, input):
        self.tfDict = dict()
        self.stemmedWords = []
        self.lemmatizedWords = ""
        self.stemmedWordsRem = []
        self.sentences = []
```

The Fix AttributeError error occurs when you are trying to use the `this` keyword to reference these instance variables (try to not import `this`) instead of using `self` keyword.