# what is "s" attribute of "this" class?

Tags: python

With below code we see a weird output of `s` attribute of `this` class of python.

```
>>> import this
>>> dir(this)
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'c', 'd', 'i', 's']
>>> this.s
"Gur Mra bs Clguba, ol Gvz Crgref\n\nOrnhgvshy vf orggre guna htyl.\nRkcyvpvg vf orggre guna vzcyvpvg.\nFvzcyr vf orggre guna pbzcyrk.\nPbzcyrk vf orggre guna pbzcyvpngrq.\nSyng vf orggre guna arfgrq.\nFcnefr vf orggre guna qrafr.\nErnqnovyvgl pbhagf.\nFcrpvny pnfrf nera'g fcrpvny rabhtu gb oernx gur ehyrf.\nNygubhtu cenpgvpnyvgl orngf chevgl.\nReebef fubhyq arire cnff fvyragyl.\nHayrff rkcyvpvgyl fvyraprq.\nVa gur snpr bs nzovthvgl, ershfr gur grzcgngvba gb thrff.\nGurer fubhyq or bar-- naq cersrenoyl bayl bar --boivbhf jnl gb qb vg.\nNygubhtu gung jnl znl abg or boivbhf ng svefg hayrff lbh'er Qhgpu.\nAbj vf orggre guna arire.\nNygubhtu arire vf bsgra orggre guna *evtug* abj.\nVs gur vzcyrzragngvba vf uneq gb rkcynva, vg'f n onq vqrn.\nVs gur vzcyrzragngvba vf rnfl gb rkcynva, vg znl or n tbbq vqrn.\nAnzrfcnprf ner bar ubaxvat terng vqrn -- yrg'f qb zber bs gubfr!"
```

What is the meaning of this output? and what is the use of it?

Comment: Just try `print(this.s.decode('rot13'))`, you will see it's encoded version of Zen.

Comment: it is encrypted text of `Zen of Python`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[It's just part of the source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/this.py).

```
s = """Gur Mra bs Clguba, ol Gvz Crgref

Ornhgvshy vf orggre guna htyl.
Rkcyvpvg vf orggre guna vzcyvpvg.
Fvzcyr vf orggre guna pbzcyrk.
Pbzcyrk vf orggre guna pbzcyvpngrq.
Syng vf orggre guna arfgrq.
Fcnefr vf orggre guna qrafr.
Ernqnovyvgl pbhagf.
Fcrpvny pnfrf nera'g fcrpvny rabhtu gb oernx gur ehyrf.
Nygubhtu cenpgvpnyvgl orngf chevgl.
Reebef fubhyq arire cnff fvyragyl.
Hayrff rkcyvpvgyl fvyraprq.
Va gur snpr bs nzovthvgl, ershfr gur grzcgngvba gb thrff.
Gurer fubhyq or bar-- naq cersrenoyl bayl bar --boivbhf jnl gb qb vg.
Nygubhtu gung jnl znl abg or boivbhf ng svefg hayrff lbh'er Qhgpu.
Abj vf orggre guna arire.
Nygubhtu arire vf bsgra orggre guna *evtug* abj.
Vs gur vzcyrzragngvba vf uneq gb rkcynva, vg'f n onq vqrn.
Vs gur vzcyrzragngvba vf rnfl gb rkcynva, vg znl or n tbbq vqrn.
Anzrfcnprf ner bar ubaxvat terng vqrn -- yrg'f qb zber bs gubfr!"""

d = {}
for c in (65, 97):
    for i in range(26):
        d[chr(i+c)] = chr((i+13) % 26 + c)

print("".join([d.get(c, c) for c in s]))
```

The joke is on Tim, because this code prints out *The Zen of Python*, but is written in a way that violates all of suggestions listed there.

Comment: Related "[that](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/that)" and the AntiZen of Python

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855758/can-anyone-explain-me-the-source-code-of-python-import-this