# Why is the text in `this` module ROT13 encoded?

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, cpython

If we open the Python interpreter and type `import this` it will print the *Zen of python*. From the Python [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/this.py) this text is generated by following piece of code.

```
s = """Gur Mra bs Clguba, ol Gvz Crgref

Ornhgvshy vf orggre guna htyl.
Rkcyvpvg vf orggre guna vzcyvpvg.
Fvzcyr vf orggre guna pbzcyrk.
Pbzcyrk vf orggre guna pbzcyvpngrq.
Syng vf orggre guna arfgrq.
Fcnefr vf orggre guna qrafr.
Ernqnovyvgl pbhagf.
Fcrpvny pnfrf nera'g fcrpvny rabhtu gb oernx gur ehyrf.
Nygubhtu cenpgvpnyvgl orngf chevgl.
Reebef fubhyq arire cnff fvyragyl.
Hayrff rkcyvpvgyl fvyraprq.
Va gur snpr bs nzovthvgl, ershfr gur grzcgngvba gb thrff.
Gurer fubhyq or bar-- naq cersrenoyl bayl bar --boivbhf jnl gb qb vg.
Nygubhtu gung jnl znl abg or boivbhf ng svefg hayrff lbh'er Qhgpu.
Abj vf orggre guna arire.
Nygubhtu arire vf bsgra orggre guna *evtug* abj.
Vs gur vzcyrzragngvba vf uneq gb rkcynva, vg'f n onq vqrn.
Vs gur vzcyrzragngvba vf rnfl gb rkcynva, vg znl or n tbbq vqrn.
Anzrfcnprf ner bar ubaxvat terng vqrn -- yrg'f qb zber bs gubfr!"""

d = {}
for c in (65, 97):
    for i in range(26):
        d[chr(i+c)] = chr((i+13) % 26 + c)

print "".join([d.get(c, c) for c in s])
```

I have read [What is the source code of the "this" module doing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855758/what-is-the-source-code-of-the-this-module-doing) From the accepted answer I understood that the `s` variable text is ROT13 encoded and the last 6 lines

```
d = {}
for c in (65, 97):
    for i in range(26):
        d[chr(i+c)] = chr((i+13) % 26 + c)

print "".join([d.get(c, c) for c in s])
```

will decode by building translation table and printing out to the console.

Why it is encoded? In other words, why it is not written like this:

```
s = """
The Zen of Python, by Tim Peters

Beautiful is better than ugly.
Explicit is better than implicit.
Simple is better than complex.
Complex is better than complicated.
Flat is better than nested.
Sparse is better than dense.
Readability counts.
Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.
Although practicality beats purity.
Errors should never pass silently.
Unless explicitly silenced.
In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.
There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.
Although that way may not be obvious at first unless you're Dutch.
Now is better than never.
Although never is often better than *right* now.
If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea.
If the implementation is easy to explain, it may be a good idea.
Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!"""

print(s)
```

Note: I searched similar question in SO but could not find helpful links.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855758/what-is-the-source-code-of-the-this-module-doing#comment40459179_5855793) from @abarnert here says it all:

> As a joke. Everything the module does, from obfuscating the source
>   code to implementing rot13 from scratch even though it's built into
>   the stdlib, directly violates the Zen of Python. Tim Peters also snuck
>   some subtle jokes into the Zen itself (notice the dashes on the
>   TOOWTDI line do it two different ways?)

Furthermore, [efforts were made to remove the encoding](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/d310f13cd2c321f0cca8429f611546c7888ae561), but it was [rolled back in a subsequent PR](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/0a83778572276c2ed0c7d3184508a4a1635c2f94).